# Flutter app works on physical device. On Android emulator: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = ... (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I did loose a lot of time trying to solve this problem. Running my app on my Android Galaxy S20 smartphone did not generate this exception. But executing it on a Pixel_3a_API_33 emulator caused the "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '...' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" to be thrown.

My Android\app\AndroidManifest.xml was correct:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatgpt_audio_learn">
   <applicationPixel_3a_API_33
        android:label="chatgpt_audio_learn"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"> 
        <!-- Previous line enables giving storage access permission to the application 
         on Galaxy S8 and S20 -->        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Next line solves the file access problem on Galaxy S20 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Next line enables downloading info on Galaxy S8 and S20 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> no effect-->
</manifest>
```

So, how to solve this annoying problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem using Android Studio: I deleted the Pixel_3a_API_33 emulator and then recreated it. Now, my app no longer causes this FileSystemException.